# How can I test get and set by vitest or jests

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, vitest

I'm testing my user class, but the coverage certainly points out that I should have tested it.

It points out the get and sets and I have no idea how I can run a test to cover it.

```
export class User {
  props: IUserPros
  get id() { return this.props.id }
  get name() { return this.props.name }
  get email() { return this.props.email }
  get password() { return this.props.password }
  set password(value: string) { this.props.password = value }

  constructor(props: IUserPros, private validator: IValidator, id?: string) {
    if (props.name === '') {
      throw new Error('Name is not valid')
    }
    
    // 1 - Validate the email - How is a validation that only depends on itself (can be done here)
    if (!this.validator.email(props.email)) {
      throw new Error('E-mail is not valid')
    }
    delete this.validator // remove validator object from props

    if (!id) {
      props.id = uuid()
    }

    this.props = props
  }
}
```

The coverage points out the following errors.

```bash
Test Files  1 passed (1)
     Tests  2 passed (2)
  Start at  20:12:17
  Duration  558ms (transform 339ms, setup 0ms, collect 155ms, tests 2ms)

 % Coverage report from istanbul
---------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                  |   43.75 |    66.66 |   28.57 |   43.75 |                   
 entities/user             |   35.71 |    66.66 |   16.66 |   35.71 |                   
  User.ts                  |   35.71 |    66.66 |   16.66 |   35.71 | 35-39,50-56       
 infra/providers/validator |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  validator.ts             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Though it looks kind of pointless since there's no modification to the input, you could create an object of that class, get its values, and validate that they match.

```js
it('should handle getters', () => {
    const user = new User(/* user stuff */);
    except(user.name).toBe(/* user name in constructor */)
    // ...
});
```

And then perform some setting and validate that it matches:

```js
it('should handle setters', () => {
    const user = new User(/* user stuff */);
    user.password = /* new password */;
    except(user.password).toBe(/* new password */)
    // ...
});
```

But, since the constructor has some validation for the input, I guess other setter methods should have that validation if needed.